# how to input multiline statements into arangosh?

Tags: arangodb

as far as I know the only way to register aqlfunctions is via arangosh. JS functions very fastly get a few more lines of code which normally also have line breaks for better understanding. Whenever I paste them into the arangosh it gets corrupt as it excepts to get a "proper" end signal/sign. If I don't know it , the only way to reset it is a shotdown. My questions are:

1. Is there any shortcut like  which resets the line input in such a case?
2. How can I write JS code into several lines and paste them into the arangosh directly?
3. Is there another way to register (more complex) JS functions I don't know?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I tried the following: arangosh [_system]> a = function() {<NL>
..................> return 1;<NL>
..................> }<NL>
(<NL> meaning press "enter")
which worked. Can you give an example?

Comment: regarding 1. under Linux you can press "ctr-D"

Comment: a workaround: `require("internal").load(filename);` will execute code from the given file inside the ArangoShell.

Comment: I just tried it on Windows and it looked like entering a multiline function definition (using several newlines) worked fine there, too. However, when copying multiline code and pasting it into the ArangoShell, only the first line of the original code got pasted.

Comment: I patched the linenoise implementation that we're using on Windows. This should fix the problem that when pasting multi-line strings into the ArangoShell, it would stop at the first newline. The fix will be included in the next releases (2.5 and devel).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<STRG> + D` also works in windows.

Multiline doesn't work well with the CMD, it works partly with the cygwin shell window.
However, if the context shows that a function will start (using a brace) it will offer to add another line until the brace closes.

Probably the easiest way to get in more complex code is:

```
require("internal").load("c:\\tmp\\test.js")
```

which will be executed right away, so if you define functions in that, they will be usable in the shell context from then on.